# Html size is too long - Bing Webmaster Tool

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, blogs

I ran a site scan with Bing Webmaster Tool, and some of my pages came back with the issue "Html size is too long". One example is this one: https://bellawanana.com/free-starbucks/

I am not too sure how to fix it. Bing says that it may be because the page contains large amounts of CSS or code at the top, but there is nothing unusual about this page (no special formatting).

Can you provide some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your source code is too long. (too many lines or a filesize). It is caused because the long content.

Best solution is to load unimportant content (comments, pingbacks) asynchronously.

I can see, that you are using wordpress, so I assume taht you don't have much coding skills (I am sorry if I am wrong), so best option for you is to split this page into more separate pages.

Comment: Yes I don't have much coding skills. How do I load unimportant comments asynchronously? I can potentially delete pingbacks I think.

Comment: using ajax - simply you run javascript code (after page load) to download content from some url and append it to the body or elsewhere

Comment: when user clicks to the second part of content it is lowering your bounce rate which is also positive for you